# How to do Phone Authentication in Flutter using Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have searched many websites and I didn't find a way to implement phone authentication in Flutter using Firebase. Can anyone tell me how to this?

Comment: You could mimic https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth or checkout https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/10404 which links to https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/firebase_auth (lmgtfy: phone authentication flutter)

Comment: I have implemented the phone auth on Node.js, but stuck at right there. Do you have any advice for using web phone auth as a WebView on Flutter? For example, how can a Flutter app know that the user is logged in or not after authorized by phone auth?

Comment: Please find the answer to this question below.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Well Documented Working Demo project [here](https://github.com/mohith7548/Firebase-Phone-Auth-Demo)

Below is the detailed procedure

### Steps

1. Ask for user's phoneNumber
2. Get OTP from Firebase
3. SignIn to Firebase

### Rules

- SignIn/Login is done in the same way.
- The OTP is only used to get `AuthCrendential` object
- `AuthCredential` object is the only thing that is used to signIn the user.
  It is obtained either from `verificationCompleted` callback function in `verifyPhoneNumber` or from the `PhoneAuthProvider`.

(Don't worry if it's confusing, keep reading, you'll get it)

### Workflow

1. User gives the `phoneNumber`
2. Firebase sends OTP
3. SignIn the user

   - If the SIM card with the `phoneNumber` is not in the device that is currently running the app,

     - We have to first ask the OTP and get `AuthCredential` object
     - Next we can use that `AuthCredential` to signIn
       This method works even if the `phoneNumber` is in the device
   - Else if user provided SIM phoneNumber is in the device running the app,

     - We can signIn without the OTP.
     - because the `verificationCompleted` callback from `submitPhoneNumber` function gives the `AuthCredential` object which is needed to signIn the user
     - But in the previous case, it ain't called because the SIM is not in the phone.

### Functions

- SubmitPhoneNumber

```dart
Future<void> _submitPhoneNumber() async {
    /// NOTE: Either append your phone number country code or add in the code itself
    /// Since I'm in India we use "+91 " as prefix `phoneNumber`
    String phoneNumber = "+91 " + _phoneNumberController.text.toString().trim();
    print(phoneNumber);

    /// The below functions are the callbacks, separated so as to make code more readable
    void verificationCompleted(AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
      print('verificationCompleted');
      ...
      this._phoneAuthCredential = phoneAuthCredential;
      print(phoneAuthCredential);
    }

    void verificationFailed(AuthException error) {
      ...
      print(error);
    }

    void codeSent(String verificationId, [int code]) {
      ...
      print('codeSent');
    }

    void codeAutoRetrievalTimeout(String verificationId) {
      ...
      print('codeAutoRetrievalTimeout');
    }

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      /// Make sure to prefix with your country code
      phoneNumber: phoneNumber,

      /// `seconds` didn't work. The underlying implementation code only reads in `milliseconds`
      timeout: Duration(milliseconds: 10000),

      /// If the SIM (with phoneNumber) is in the current device this function is called.
      /// This function gives `AuthCredential`. Moreover `login` function can be called from this callback
      verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,

      /// Called when the verification is failed
      verificationFailed: verificationFailed,

      /// This is called after the OTP is sent. Gives a `verificationId` and `code`
      codeSent: codeSent,

      /// After automatic code retrival `tmeout` this function is called
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout,
    ); // All the callbacks are above
  }
```

- SubmitOTP

```dart
void _submitOTP() {
    /// get the `smsCode` from the user
    String smsCode = _otpController.text.toString().trim();

    /// when used different phoneNumber other than the current (running) device
    /// we need to use OTP to get `phoneAuthCredential` which is inturn used to signIn/login
    this._phoneAuthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: this._verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);

    _login();
  }
```

- SignIn/LogIn

```dart
Future<void> _login() async {
    /// This method is used to login the user
    /// `AuthCredential`(`_phoneAuthCredential`) is needed for the signIn method
    /// After the signIn method from `AuthResult` we can get `FirebaserUser`(`_firebaseUser`)
    try {
      await FirebaseAuth.instance
          .signInWithCredential(this._phoneAuthCredential)
          .then((AuthResult authRes) {
        _firebaseUser = authRes.user;
        print(_firebaseUser.toString());
      });
      ...
    } catch (e) {
      ...
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

- Logout

```dart
  Future<void> _logout() async {
    /// Method to Logout the `FirebaseUser` (`_firebaseUser`)
    try {
      // signout code
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
      _firebaseUser = null;
      ...
    } catch (e) {
      ...
      print(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

For more details on implementation please refer to the `lib/main.dart` file [here](https://github.com/mohith7548/Firebase-Phone-Auth-Demo/blob/master/lib/main.dart).

If you found issues, edits are welcome to this answer and to this [repo README](https://github.com/mohith7548/Firebase-Phone-Auth-Demo)

Comment: I tried it this app is crashing in android and not getting installed in iOS. I took the whole code updated packages as per google.json file generated from firebase.

Comment: @codeFreak I don't have MacBook, so you need to configure things on iOS side. Moreover, I checked again & the app is working. Please try configuring on the Firebase side or make sure you have internet connection enabled on the testing device. I can't figure out where it might have gone wrong for you. Try all possibilities.

Comment: @Mohith7548 I am trying to implement this in a flutter app which google email address for registration. So, will I be able to use phone authentication as the authentication process is handled based on the email address? I just need to implement the OTP verification in the app.

Comment: @Bhawna Firebase offers different auth providers and you can turn them on in authentication section. You can use email or phone number to sign in a user. But both at a time is not possible.

Answer (score 7):

Currently `_signInPhoneNumber` is deprecated, so use this:

```
try {
    AuthCredentialauthCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId: verificationId, verificationsCode: smsCode);

    await _firebaseAuth
      .signInWithCredential(authCredential)
      .then((FirebaseUser user) async {
         final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
         assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);
         print('signed in with phone number successful: user -> $user');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Below are the steps:-

1. Get OTP based on Phone Number:-

   ```
   void sendOTP(String phoneNumber, PhoneCodeSent codeSent,
         PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed) {
       if (!phoneNumber.contains('+')) phoneNumber = '+91' + phoneNumber;
       _firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
           phoneNumber: phoneNumber,
           timeout: Duration(seconds: 30),
           verificationCompleted: null,
           verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
           codeSent: codeSent,
           codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: null);   }
   ```
2. Use the codeSent function to retrieve verification_id and pass it to OTP screen

   ```
   void codeSent(String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) {
   Navigator.push(
       context,
       MaterialPageRoute(
           builder: (context) => Otp(
                 phoneNumber: _phoneNumber,
                 verificationId: verificationId,
               )));
   }
   ```
3. Get user based on verification_id and OTP

   ```
   Future<bool> verifyOTP(String verificationId, String otp) async {
   AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
     verificationId: verificationId,
     smsCode: otp,
   );
   AuthResult result;
   try {
     result = await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential);
   } catch (e) {
     // throw e;
     return false;
   }
   print(result);
   (await result.user.getIdToken()).claims.forEach((k, v) {
     print('k= $k and v= $v');
   });
   if (result.user.uid != null) return true;
   return false;
   }
   ```

For more details watch the below [video](https://youtu.be/e5M3EwJJYS4)

https://youtu.be/e5M3EwJJYS4

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but I was building an Ionic app.

you can do firebase phone auth on the web.
the idea is:

- take the user's phone number and send to a webpage.
- create a recaptchaVerifier

  ```
  var recaptchaVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier('recaptcha-container');
  ```
- sign in the user with phone number:

  ```
  firebase.auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(phoneNumber, recaptchaVerifier)
          .then(confirmationResult => {
              myVerificationId = confirmationResult.verificationId;
          })
          .catch(error => {
              console.log('error', error);
          })
  ```
- send the confirmation id back to the flutter app through a deeplink
- Firebase will send the sms code.
- sign in the user with any method that takes the confirmation Id and
  the code as parameters. for the web it goes like this:

  ```
    let signinCredintial = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(this.verificationId, this.code);
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(signinCredintial)
     .then(response => {
       // user is signed in

  })
  ```

Comment: I understand it. There should be a method to do firebase phone authentication. As shown above, "signInWithPhoneNumber" method is not available with the Firebase object.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented the phone auth singnIn with firebase in flutter its quite easy just import the firebase_auth library and validate the phone number is in proper format i.e it has a "+" sign in the beginning followed by country code then the phone number then the code goes like this

```
if (phoneExp.hasMatch(phon))
   {
      final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted=(FirebaseUser user){
        setState(() {
                      _message=Future<String>.value("auto sign in succedded $user");
                      debugPrint("Sign up succedded");
                      _pref.setString("phonkey",user.phoneNumber.toString());
                      MyNavigator.goToDetail(context);
//called when the otp is variefied automatically
                    });
      };
  final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed=(AuthException authException){
    setState(() {
                  _message=Future<String>.value("verification failed code: ${authException.code}. Message: ${authException.message}");
                });
  };

  final PhoneCodeSent codeSent=(String verificationId,[int forceResendingToken]) async {
    this.verificationId=verificationId;


  };

  final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout = (String verificationId){
    this.verificationId=verificationId;

  };

  await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: phon,
    timeout: Duration(seconds: 60),
    verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
    verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
    codeSent: codeSent,
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout
    );



}
```

and if the phone wasn't able to detect the otp sent automatically, get the otp in a string and implement this function

```
void _signInWithOtp() async{
  final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithPhoneNumber(
  verificationId: verificationId,
  smsCode: _otpController.text,
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [flutter_otp](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_otp) package to send SMS with OTP easily. The advantages are:

1. You can send custom OTP messages.
2. OTP can be generated in any range.

Example of using it :

```
 import 'package:flutter_otp/flutter_otp.dart';

 ...

 FlutterOtp myOtpObj = FlutterOtp();
 myOtpObj.sendOtp('7975235555');

 ...

 // you can check as follows
 bool correctOrNot = myOtpObj.resultChecker(<OTP entered by user>);
```

Check out the flutter_otp repository [here](https://github.com/JerinFrancisA/flutter_otp)

Comment: Who pays for the SMS in this package?